# JavaFX Media Exception. Could not create player

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans-8.1

I've been trying to make a simple GUI player in Java with JavaFX. It works fine until i try to open a file. It just throw a stack and do nothing.

**STACK**

```
Executing /home/julius/Templates/Java-Projects/JavaFXApplication1/dist/run1593625829/JavaFXApplication1.jar using platform /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
Prism-ES2 Error : GL_VERSION (major.minor) = 1.4

(java:4134): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",

(java:4134): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
```

**FilePath is- file:///home/julius/Videos/MOVIES/SAW/sAw/Saw.mp4**

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$5(GtkApplication.java:139)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
... 48 more
Caused by: MediaException: UNKNOWN : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player! : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
at javafx.scene.media.MediaException.exceptionToMediaException(MediaException.java:146)
at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:511)
at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.<init>(MediaPlayer.java:414)
at javafxapplication1.FXMLDocumentController.handleButtonAction(FXMLDocumentController.java:47)
... 58 more
Caused by: com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.getPlayer(NativeMediaManager.java:274)
at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaManager.getPlayer(MediaManager.java:118)
at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:467)
... 60 more
Deleting directory /home/julius/Templates/Java-Projects/JavaFXApplication1/dist/run1593625829
jfxsa-run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 58 seconds)
```

**[EDIT-1]**

```
package javafxapplication1;


import java.io.File;
import java.net.
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
private String filePath;

@FXML
private MediaPlayer mp;
@FXML
private MediaView mv;
@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {}

@FXML
public void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    FileChooser fc= new FileChooser();
    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extensionFilter= new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Video files with mp4 extension only.", "*.mp4");
    fc.getExtensionFilters().add(extensionFilter);
    
    File file= fc.showOpenDialog(null);
    filePath= file.toURI().toString();
            
    if(filePath!= null) {
                System.out.println("FilePath is- "+filePath);
        Media media= new Media(filePath);
        mp= new MediaPlayer(media);
        mv.setMediaPlayer(mp);
        DoubleProperty width= mv.fitWidthProperty();
        DoubleProperty height= mv.fitHeightProperty();
        width.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(mv.sceneProperty(), "width"));
        height.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(mv.sceneProperty(), "height"));
        mp.play();
    }
}

@FXML public void playButton(ActionEvent event) {mp.play(); mp.setRate(1);}
@FXML public void pauseButton(ActionEvent event) {mp.pause();}
@FXML public void stopButton(ActionEvent event) {mp.stop();}
@FXML public void forwardButton(ActionEvent event) {}
@FXML public void rewindButton(ActionEvent event) {}
@FXML public void fasterButton(ActionEvent event) {mp.setRate(2);}
@FXML public void slowerButton(ActionEvent event) {mp.setRate(0.5);}
@FXML public void exitButton(ActionEvent event) {Platform.exit();}
}
```

---

The path seems alright and i can't figure there's anything wrong with my **controller source** let me know if anyone want to see the source. How can i fix this **unknown** Exception ?

> **Several things to keep in mind**
>
> - Java version is
>
>   openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
>
>   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-8u151-b12-0ubuntu0.17.10.2-b12)
>
>   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
> - I'm using Netbeans IDE with all javafx plugins installed.

Comment: Refer [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774664/gtk-warning-unable-to-locate-theme-engine-in-module-path-adwaita-error-o)

Comment: @StabCode Thank you for commenting! I did what that link told me to do and it did sort the GTk warning. However exception is still there.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]

Comment: @JimGarrison Added Controller source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted this out by installing **Java 9.0.4** and **Intellij IDE**. Netbeans 8.2 isn't compatible with java 9. The code was all right.

**UPDATED CODE**

The controller source has been updated to make it compatible with java9. For some reason **java.nio.file.Paths;** isn't working with the latest java.